# How to delete a Catalina Beta from a disk with Dual-Boot Mojave and Catalina Beta

Tags: mojave, dual-boot, catalina

I have a disk with DualBoot Mojave and Catalina Beta in a single container. Catalina Beta has two volumes: 'MacOSBeta' and 'MacOSBeta - Data'.

I want to delete the Catalina Beta os. Is it as simple as deleting the Catalina Beta volumes?

Comment: Do you have one APFS container? Most good dual boot guides for Catalina should be like that, but let’s clarify if possible.

Comment: @bmike yes, both are in the same container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, APFS containers make it trivial to erase a volume since the free space commingles, you can walk away from the data once you’re sure you have a back up or don’t need one.